# Android NDK : How to handle Back key press in Cocos2dx?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

The question is all I have to say about it. I need to know how to handle the special keypresses like `back`, `menu` etc. in android NDK. I am using Cocos2dX so if you could give me a Cocos2dX specif answer that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In cocos2dx, each `CCLayer` gets the following methods that can be overriden to add functionality to them:

```
class CC_DLL CCKeypadDelegate
{
public:
    // The back key clicked
    virtual void keyBackClicked() {}

    // The menu key clicked. only avialble on wophone & android
    virtual void keyMenuClicked() {};
};
```

`CCLayer` inherits from `CCKeypadDelegate`. And each screen can give implementation to these functions.

Comment: I think you might need to add setKeypadEnabled(true); somewhere to make it work.

Comment: Just be sure that you are using coco2d-x 2.1 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

In Cocos2d-x
You have to do that
implement

```
 virtual void keyBackClicked();
```

and also this

```
 this->setKeyPadEnable(true);
```

in .cpp class

Answer (score 1):

Enable keypad : `this->setKeypadEnabled(true);`

Override onKeyReleased method :
    `virtual void onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event);`

Check for keyCode:

```
void GameScene::onKeyReleased(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    if (keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_BACKSPACE) {
        CCLOG("You pressed back button");
    }
    else if(keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_MENU)
    {
        CCLOG("You pressed menu button");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class is not inherit with `CClayer`, then you can handle this through `JNI` calls.
In `Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java` you handle back and menu key from `onKeyDown` function

```
public boolean onKeyDown(final int pKeyCode, final KeyEvent pKeyEvent)
```